# Linux system call to translate virtual to physical address

Tags: linux-kernel

I am using code similar to that given below to map a system-call-supplied virtual address to a physical address (taken from http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=29961&seqNum=3):

```
print_pa (struct mm_struct *mm, unsigned long va) {
    pgd t *pgd = pgd_offset(mm, va);
    if (pgd_present(*pgd)) {
        pmd t *pmd = pmd_offset(pgd, va);
        if (pmd_present(*pmd)) {
            pte_t *pte = pte_offset(pmd, va);
            if (pte_present(*pte)) {
                printk("va 0x%lx -> pa 0x%lx\n",
                    va, page_address(pte_page(*pte));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Am I using page_address() correctly? It gives me back addresses like 0xdded1000 yet I only have 1GB of RAM on the machine.The following web page says page_address() returns a physical address but my results are not making sense (to me) https://kernel.org/doc/gorman/html/understand/understand023.html.

Comment: Physical address space is not only a RAM, check cat /proc/iomem

Comment: `page_address` returns a virtual address, not a physical one. However, where is `va` coming from? Is really an userspace virtual address?

Comment: Calling `page_to_phys(page)` rather than `page_address(page)` fixes the issue.